# Can I ask on IS Stack Exchange about the correctness of answers on a different SE?

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question on WorldBuilding SE.

[How can invading aliens access the Internet to find out all about us?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/185329/how-can-invading-aliens-access-the-internet-to-find-out-all-about-us)

I now find that I am unqualified to judge the best answer. These range from "It's impossible" to "It's easy".

**Question**

Is there any on-topic question I can ask on IS that will help me judge the answers?

**For example**

I could ask an expert here to judge for me - but that seems unlikely to be on-topic.

I could ask a similar but more specific question here and compare the results.

Something else that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 4):

The question you've asked is not a security question, so it would not be on-topic here. You're asking about networking basics.

And Renan's answer has the technical details you require.

Comment: Thanks. One of my concerns that the aliens would at least have to break through *some* security barriers but, if that's not an issue I'll accept your advice.